# Father in law possible pedophile

Tags: family

I’m dealing with a very tricky situation. I innocently came across my father in law liking photos of minor children on Facebook. My heart was pounding like there must be some sort of mistake here. Nope. I dug deep and found over 200+ photos of him liking. All minor children in swimsuits, regular clothing but short shorts, see through shirts and even shorts showing body parts. My husband now knows and we are so deeply disturbed. We do not know how to bring this up in a way that he doesn’t do something rash. I don’t think he would but you never know. We have two young boys and this is not ok for them to be around someone like this. We do not have a good relationship with his parents just very distant but this needs to be spoken about. Even if we have boys this is still not ok. We are in a tough position and a very awkward one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question. You already stated you don't have much of a relationship with the parents. If the question is "What should we do?", then it's opinion based. I'm not sure it's even about your children (i.e. parenting.) Maybe on IPS.SE?

Comment: That’s rude. I said we do need to bring this up just because we are distant doesn’t mean I still don’t see them. I don’t know how to bring it up in a way that he’s not gonna do something to himself or us.

Comment: That's not a parenting issue. That's an interpersonal issue.

Comment: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41304/how-can-i-protect-my-children-from-a-pedophile-uncle?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.4580

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan - That post had a question pertinent to parenting.

Comment: @anongoodnurse True, I just linked it in case it might help the OP. Sorry I did not clarify why I sent it .

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan - Oh! That was very thoughtful of you, seriously. Thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Start by educating your children about touch safety, especially emphasizing that this includes loved ones, but not making mention of any particular person.

You will have to ensure that the children don't meet alone with their grandfather until adulthood.

No point in bringing this up with FIL.